# What is the largest data type for storing (and printing) an integer?

Tags: c, types, int, long-integer, primitive-types

In C on a 32-bit system, which data type will store (and can therefore print) the largest integer? Is it `long long` or `unsigned long`? Is there an `unsigned long long`? And which is the most precise and politically correct?

Comment: If you're just concerned with the ability to display large numbers, I'd vote for char*. :)

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question. *How high do you need to go?*

Comment: Yes, C99 supports an `unsigned long long` primitive type, but C90 doesn't. And since lots of C compilers out there in the wild are still C90, the answer might be no. Which one are you using/interested in?

Comment: char* can print an integer Chris?? Limitless?

Comment: _int64 ? does not work ? more precise ?

Comment: @HichamfromCppDependTeam it's not a standard type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but `intmax_t` is the largest signed integer-valued type (and `uintmax_t` is the largest unsigned integer type).  These are typedefs defined in `<stdint.h>`, but if you are printing them, you need `<inttypes.h>` instead, and the PRInMAX macros for various values of *n*.

Comment: And `uintmax_t` (if the implementation supports them; they were added in C99).

Comment: dont `%jd` and `%ju` work (and look better) for printing `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` respectivelly? Source: - [the latest freely available c11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), see section 7.21.6.1 on `fprintf`

Comment: E.g. to print in octal format `PRI(o)MAX`

Answer (score 3):

In ISO C99 `long long` is at least 64bit which is the largest standard integer data type. It also comes as `unsigned long long`. Apparently your compiler might provide larger types wich defined by `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`.

However based on your comments you might be looking for a bigint library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). It allows for arbitrary long integers (and floating point) limited in length only by your system resources.

Comment: Yes (note that `long long` and `unsigned long long` are distinct types), but implementations can have *extended integer types* that are wider than `long long`.  The typedefs `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`, correspond to the largest signed and unsigned types, respectively, whether they're extended types or not.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks I incorporated that.

Answer (score 2):

Without beating around the bush I would like to say that sometimes not in actual coding practice bt yes defintly in some competitions one might need very big data types bt I think we can do this. Why not take the entire sequence in the form of string and then use the atoi function to get the integer value it is I think politcally correct :: :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    char bigString [256];

    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    fgets (bigString, 256, stdin);

    i = atoi (bigString);
    printf ("The value entered is %d.",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still need to store the converted value to an integer which still causes overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The data type with the longest printed string is a signed data type, unless you have an integer type that has a maximum unsigned value that is one digit longer than the maximum signed value.

For example, a 4-bit integer unsigned would be at most two characters unsigned or one character plus the negative sign when signed.

So, you should pick a signed data type to represent the largest printed string. Which should be `long long`.

Comment: the longest printed string for `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are `-9223372036854775808` and `18446744073709551615` respectively, which have the same length