# how to store and print sixteen digits number in hexadecimal format in Turbo C?

Tags: c, turbo-c

I tried to store and print a sixteen digits number in hexadecimal format in `Turbo C` by typing the coding

```
long long unsigned num=0x35647882781256532
```

But it prints only last eight digits. When I tried in Ubuntu, it prints all the sixteen digit numbers. Please help me how to print all the sixteen digits in hexadecimal format in `Turbo C`.

Comment: `Turbo C` is pretty old and mostly known for non-conformance with C standards. Do you have a chance to upgrade to `gcc`?

Comment: Show minimal complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What does your printing code look like?

Comment: I'm surprised it even allows `long long`! Turbo C is *ancient*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22981285/4627552
This is an easy way to store and print a large number.

Comment: `printf("%llx\n", num)`?

Comment: Do you need a size suffix such as `LL` on the hex literal, e.g. `0x0123456789abcdefLL`? (Btw, your number has 17 hex digits.)

Comment: Did you check what `sizeof(long long)` returns on both compilers?

Comment: If all else fails, `typedef struct { unsigned long lo,hi; } ulong64;` and `printf("%08x%08x\n",num.hi,num.lo);`

Comment: Are we talking the legacy Turbo-C platform?  If so, it simply doesn't support integers of that width.

Answer (score 1):

Borland C++ 5.1, the direct successor of TurboC, is pretty old (1993) and works with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    __int64 d = 0x1234567890123456;

    printf("%Lx\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

`%Lx` or `%Ld` is the printf parameter to print 64 bits integers.

Comment: I tried all the above codes, it didn't work. Please clearly explain all your codes, like how to declare the sixteen digit number and how to print the number. My original code is "unsigned long long num=0x1234567890123456; printf("%llx\n", num);"

Comment: @alex wahique "it didn't work" is not helpful.  Rather report what _did_  happen.  Joël Hecht has a nice answer.  You want "explain all your codes" yet did not show any code in your _post_.